# How can I sort dataframe based on a complicated string column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm needing to sort a dataframe based on a string column, which is composed of a variety of letters, numbers, dashes, and string lengths. I'm not even sure sorting is the right method of what I want to do. Example below:

df

```
Col1    Col2
  A    80NX-265-DF23
  B    D-87-B-003
  C    80NX-265-DF23
  D    0333-DD-02
  E    D-87-B-003
  F    80NX-265-DF23
```

Desired DF:

```
Col1     Col2
 A      80NX-265-DF23
 C      80NX-265-DF23
 F      80NX-265-DF23
 D      0333-DD-02
 B      D-87-B-003
 E      D-87-B-003
```

The order/sorting of either column does not matter, I just want the dataframe reordered and 'grouped' on column2. Grouped might not be the right expression here either cause I don't want to perform any sort of aggregated calculation. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `df.sort_values(['Col2','Col1'],ascending=[False,True])
` ?

Comment: The string column in Col2 is too complicated for using sort_values.

Comment: whats the logic of the sorting

Comment: but `sort_values` works in the data sample you gave, doesn't it? It "groups" the values as you wanted, regarding of the order, as you said.@dmd7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be iterration and concat:

```
pd.concat([df[df['Col2']==x] for x in df['Col2'].unique()])
```